# one-side flexible background image

Tags: css, background-image

I'm wondering how can I make a background image fixed on one side, so when the user makes the window smaller, the background image shrinks only from one side, and the other side stays clear. I got this idea because I got a background image and i need the right side of it to be always on screen. Thanks.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp start here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `background` properties to do this, most notably `background-attachment: fixed;` and `background-position: right top;` This will cause the image to "stick" to the top right of the screen.

Also, if in the future the image doesn't work, just replace it with any other placeholder image. This one was picked just to showcase the static nature of the spider's position.

```css
body {
background-image:url("http://creepyhalloweenimages.com/free_halloween_photos/backgrounds/spider_orange_copyspace.jpg");
background-attachment: fixed;
background-position: right top;
background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: are you sure background-attachement is needed here ? i don't think so ... also your code i wrong but it works ... you add height:100% to body but there is no height:100% to html -> your body actually has height=0 but due to background propagation the background is added to the html then the canvas

Comment: @TemaniAfif Good catch on the height (and width, really), that was leftover from using a div instead of the body. And yes, the attachment is needed if OP wants the image to stay fixed to the right side, otherwise the spider will be hidden on smaller screens.

Comment: no it won't be hidden because the OP said **shrink from one side** so i don't think he talked about the scroll issue ... so attachement is usefull if we want to keep visible on scroll and not on shrink

Comment: @TemaniAfif My mistake, I thought you referenced position not attachment. Yes, the attachment property isn't necessary I guess, just depends on the OP's specific needs. Either way, I just assumed OP wanted the top right corner of his/her image to always be visible, so this would accomplish that.